# Can I count on the availability of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']?

Tags: php, environment-variables, superglobals

I am writing a web app and want to use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] for something. I can use a simpler but more manual (Needs some little hardcoding) method for that task if really necessary. Is that variable in (almost) all or majority of web servers always available? Is it wise to count on it?

I ask this because sometime in the past I heard from some guys that some of the $_SERVER variables may not be set in a considerable number of environments/web servers/OSes/... and I think I had read about that in some more trusty sources too.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `__FILE__`, on the basis that it's easier to type and read.

PHP has weird behaviour for both ways of determining the current script's filename. I base that on the output of this script:

```
var_dump(__FILE__);
var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
var_dump(realpath(__FILE__));
var_dump(realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

PHP 5.6 command line, Windows, Cygwin:

```
string(40) "/cygdrive/c/file.php"
string(8) "file.php"
string(40) "/cygdrive/c/file.php"
string(40) "/cygdrive/c/file.php"
```

PHP 5.6 command line, Windows, cmd:

```
string(31) "C:\file.php"
string(8) "file.php"
string(31) "C:\file.php"
string(31) "C:\file.php"
```

Apache + PHP 5.6, Windows:

```
string(31) "C:\file.php"
string(31) "C:/file.php"
string(31) "C:\file.php"
string(31) "C:\file.php"
```

PHP 5.4 command line, Linux:

```
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
string(8) "file.php"
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
```

Nginx + PHP 5.4, Linux:

```
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
string(35) "/var/www/blah/file.php"
```

So you'll have to see based on your situation which is best. :-)

Answer (score 0):

for that i would suggest `__FILE__` if you use one of php's own [Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)  you can be sure it will work cross platform

Comment: thank u but i cant use things such as __FILE__ for some reasons. Also I dont bother about CLI, but only web environment. I am interested/need only to know about the availability of SCRIPT_FILENAME. i mean i can be sure if i use it my app will work in all major web server software on all major web server OSes (Linux, Windows, BSD, ...).

Comment: Can't help you with arbitrary restrictions